# Subtract two numbers in Linq from SQLServer

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to subtract two numbers from data base table 
for condition : subtract of all times most less than 8

```
List<Task> ltask = ProjectDAL.GetAllTasks();
```

in DB I have Start_Time and End_time

I want to subtract Start_Time from End_time for all end and start value inDB
for ex :

```
Start_Time = 10
End_time = 16 
subtract = End_time - Start_Time = 6

var subtract = ltask.Where(x =>x.End_Time - x.Start_Time);
```

but is not working

Comment: You should hit any documentation on LinQ. 
[Msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/). 
[Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?), 
[Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?), 
[Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?), 
Join 
are consider basic operation you should at least check one exemple of each to understand what they are about.

Comment: Then check all Enumerable Method, you did cover yet. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8 it has the list of method in the left. Every method have exemple focus on description, exemple, and remake. You are lacking the basic for now. but you can cover it a really short time (<1h).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`.Select(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8):

```
var subtract = ltask.Select(x => x.End_Time - x.Start_Time);
```

Assuming that `End_Time` and `Start_Time` are `int` values, this will return an `IEnumerable<int>` object. If you enumerate this with e.g. `foreach` or `.ToList()`, it will calculate the difference for each of the items in the source list `ltask`.